# Padding is invalid and cannot be removed

Tags: c#

From a comment:

> The problem was gone once i manually set padding to NONE

---

whats wrong with this code?? VS2010 does compile it, but it gives error when run from VS2010, saying cs.close（） padding is not valid, can anyone help? thanks

```
public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] cipherData,byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create();

        alg.Key = Key;
        alg.IV = IV;
        alg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7, ;

        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms,
            alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);



        cs.Write(cipherData, 0, cipherData.Length);


        cs.Close();


        byte[] decryptedData = ms.ToArray();

        return decryptedData;
```

Comment: What created the cipherdata to start with? Perhaps the error is there, or you've mismatched the padding etc?

Comment: u mean the key and byte[] to decrypt??

Comment: this is just a sample code i borrowed from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/DotNetCrypto.aspx   it used to work, but don't know why doesnt anymore

Comment: weird thing is, i can still build it, but when vs2010 tries to run, that is when the exception shows up

Comment: "it used to work" - go back to your backup of that time...

Comment: It could be anything in the encoding+transport chain. How is your byte[] data stored?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
cs.Write(cipherData, 0, cipherData.Length);
//Add this line:
cs.FlushFinalBlock();
cs.Close();
```

Comment: ok, then like Jon Skeet said - you must be sure that the cipherData you are trying to decrypt was encrypted using the same Padding that you are using for the decryption (PaddingMode.PKCS7).

Comment: Where does cipherData come from?  If you don't set the encryption padding explicitly it might not always default to the same value - maybe you should try to set it if you can?  You say it works on XP - is it breaking on Win7?

Comment: i think you made point, the decryption algorithm might add paddings itself. The problem was gone once i manually set padding to NONE