# Rijndael padding or length is invalid

Tags: c#, aes, rijndael, encryption-symmetric

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt a string using eith Rijndael or Aes and the code below.

```
public class Crypto
{
    private const string defaultVector = "asdfg123456789";
    private const CipherMode cipherMode = CipherMode.CBC;
    //Have tried PaddingMode.ISO10126, PaddingMode.None, and PaddingMode.PKCS7
    private const PaddingMode paddingMode = PaddingMode.ISO10126;
    private const int iterations = 2;
    private static Rijndael GetCrypto(string passphrase)
    {
        var crypt = Rijndael.Create();
        crypt.Mode = cipherMode;
        crypt.Padding = paddingMode;
        crypt.BlockSize = 256;
        crypt.KeySize = 256;
        crypt.Key =
            new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passphrase, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(defaultVector), iterations).GetBytes(32);
        crypt.IV = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passphrase, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(defaultVector), iterations).GetBytes(32);
        return crypt;
    }
    public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passphrase)
    {
        byte[] clearData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);
        byte[] encryptedData;
        var crypt = GetCrypto(passphrase);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, crypt.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
                //cs.FlushFinalBlock(); //Have tried this active and commented with no change.
            }
            encryptedData = ms.ToArray();
        }
        //Changed per Xint0's answer.
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
    }
    public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string passphrase)
    {
        //Changed per Xint0's answer.
        byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        byte[] clearData;
        var crypt = GetCrypto(passphrase);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, crypt.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
                    //I have tried adding a cs.FlushFinalBlock(); here as well.
                }
                clearData = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(clearData);
    }
}
```

//Edits: I have changed over the Unicode calls to Convert.ToBase64String per Xint0's answer below.

On the cs.Write in Decrypt method, I am getting the error that "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."

I have tried setting the padding to PaddingMode.None but I get "Length of the data to encrypt is invalid." on the cs.Write in the Encrypt method.

I've looked at these and nothing they've said seems to work.

[Padding is invalid and cannot be removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061581/padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed)

[Padding is invalid and cannot be removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583112/padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed)

Stack trace shows System.Security.CryptographicException is coming from RijndaelManagedTransform.DecryptData(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount, Byte[]& outputBuffer, Int32 outputOffset, PaddingMode paddingMode, Boolean fLast).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. You are not flushing and closing the streams before calling `ms.ToArray()`. Change it to:

   ```
   ...
   using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, crypt.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
   {
       cs.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
       cs.FlushFinalBlock();
       cs.Close();
   }

   ms.Close();
   encryptedData = ms.ToArray();
   ...
   ```
2. In `Encrypt` the resulting byte array `encryptedData` is **NOT** a Unicode string, yet you are using a Unicode encoder to get a string from the byte array.  Instead of that use `System.Convert.ToBase64String()` in `Encrypt` and `System.Convert.FromBase64String()` in `Decrypt`.

In `Encrypt` do:

```
return System.Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
```

In `Decrypt` do:

```
byte[] encryptedData = System.Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
```

**EDIT**

The biggest problem is the return value of `Encrypt`. The result of encrypting the byte representation of a Unicode string is ***NOT*** a byte representation of a Unicode string.  You should not use the value of `encryptedData` with `Encoding.Unicode.GetString()` to get a string representation of the encrypted data. Use `System.Convert.ToBase64String()` to get a string representation of the encrypted data.  Please see the Remarks section in the [Encoding Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hf4sb8.aspx) MSDN Documentation.

**EDIT 2**

Note that Rijndael is not exactly AES, if you are interoperating with AES the block size should always be 128-bits, independent of the key size. For details you can read about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2006/10/09/the-differences-between-rijndael-and-aes.aspx).

Comment: I have tried every permutation of adding the cs.Close() and cs.FlushFinalBlock(). The stack trace shows the error coming from System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.DecryptData(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount, Byte[]& outputBuffer, Int32 outputOffset, PaddingMode paddingMode, Boolean fLast) which is called by CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock(). FlushFinalBlock is also called when the CryptoStream is Closed/Disposed. So I am at a loss here.

Comment: @PMontgomery Have you replaced `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(encryptedBytes)` with `System.Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData)`?  This is your biggest problem.

Comment: Yes, I have made those changes and edited the original question to reflect. It has made no change in the error.

Comment: thanks for all your help on this. I believe found the issue. It is actually something happening upstream where the passphrase was getting changed between the Encrypt/Decrypt calls. Can you guess what pair of calls has an additional unit test wrapped around it now to show that it *isn't* the problematic bit of code?

Comment: @PMontgomery please be aware that Rijndael is not exactly AES.  In AES the block size is always 128 bits, independent of the key size.

Answer (score 3):

I have spend a lot of my time for finding what was causing **CryptographicException** and I was googling too including Stackoverflow.
It was a stupid mistake (as often when programming with copy-paste) as follow:

It was throwing on method *FlushFinalBlock()* from instance of *CryptoStream*.

Look at **WRONG** code:

```
CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rj.CreateDecryptor(rj.Key, rj.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
```

I used it to encrypt so you can see *CryptoStreamMode.**Write*** but in the same instruction I was creating decryptor instead of encryptor (see second parameter in the constructor).

Be careful and check it to avoid wasting your precious time ;)

Regards
Bronek

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the issue in decrypt method was initializing an empty memory stream. when it worked when I initialized it with the cipher text byte array like this:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(cipherText);
```